# use activity indicator in many VC without duplicating code swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `ViewControllers` (A and B) in swift IOS. Both A and B loads data from internet (separately). I want to display `activityIndicator` while loading. I know I can do it the bad way by declaring it once in each VC as follows

**ViewController A**

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func activityIndicatorBegin() {
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    disableUserInteraction()

    greyView = UIView()
    greyView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    greyView.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(greyView)
}

func activityIndicatorEnd() {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    enableUserInteraction()
    self.greyView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

and do the exact same for ViewController B and call the activityIndicatorBegin and activityIndicatorEnd functions that is declared in B view controller. However, I want to make the code cleaner. How could it be done? I am trying to make code cleaner these days.

Thanks,

--UPDATE--

I would imageing something like the following code would work. But it doesnt because I cant declare variables in extensions

```
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

extension UIViewController {
    func activityIndicatorBegin() {
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    disableUserInteraction()

    greyView = UIView()
    greyView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    greyView.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(greyView)
}

func activityIndicatorEnd() {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    enableUserInteraction()
    self.greyView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create one `BaseViewController` and add these two method and declare  `activityIndicator` object inside that `BaseViewController`. Now make `BaseViewController` as parent class of all your `ViewController`. After that if you want to add the indicator simply call like this

1) Create BaseViewController

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func activityIndicatorBegin() {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        disableUserInteraction()

        greyView = UIView()
        greyView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        greyView.alpha = 0.5
        self.view.addSubview(greyView)
    }

    func activityIndicatorEnd() {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        enableUserInteraction()
        self.greyView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

2) Now assign this `BaseViewController` as parent of your all `viewController` like this

```
class ViewController1: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Now if you want to add activityIndicator call like this
        self.activityIndicatorBegin()
        //or if you want remove activityIndicator 
        self.activityIndicatorEnd()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to physically create another (Third) VC in the storyboard and assign it to BaseViewController and it does nothing? I have some updates of what I have in mind

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So basically rather than doing extension: UIviewcontroller, I change it to class and have another class inherit it. Smart

Comment: Welcome. But `extension` also helpful if you want some control like `UITextField`, `UIButton`, `UILabel` etc with some custom attributes that time `extension` is a good choice. Hope you get it. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 22):

SWIFT 4

```
extension UIView{

    func activityStartAnimating(activityColor: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        backgroundView.tag = 475647
        
        var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        activityIndicator.color = activityColor
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        backgroundView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        self.addSubview(backgroundView)
    }

    func activityStopAnimating() {
        if let background = viewWithTag(475647){
            background.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
self.view.activityStartAnimating(activityColor: UIColor.white, backgroundColor: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5))


self.view.activityStopAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to make one base clase with all code that can be duplicated in your A and B class? If this classes are doing completly different thing you can add an extension for activity indicator

Comment: One VC is tableView and another is collectionView. How do I go about doing it with extension. please see update above. Thanks

Comment: @EdwardHung you have tons of examples of global activity indicators http://mpclarkson.github.io/2016/01/06/swift-uiviewcontroller_uiactivityindicator_extension/