# Loading spinner for Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

In my app I am using alamofire to parse JSON data from a web api into my app. I would like to add a loading spinner whilst the data loads. I have had a look at:

[Alamofire Loading Indicator](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator)

But that only shows the little network icon above. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you looking for UIActivityIndicator? You must add it as a subview wherever you want it and then call start or stop refreshing on it.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @rob Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/38457815/6433023 it is not in Swift 3 but you can make it by making small changes

Comment: @rob check my answer below. It will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337897/5501433

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for activity indicator view `UIActivityIndicatorView`. This must be added manually. You can add it through the storyboard and enable `hidesWhenStopped` so the indicator is not visible when stopped.

In any case you must manually call `startAnimating` before you start the request and then `stopAnimating` when the request completes.

To do it all programmatically it would look something like this:

```
// Assuming in the view controller
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray) // Create the activity indicator
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator) // add it as a  subview
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width*0.5, y: view.frame.size.height*0.5) // put in the middle
        activityIndicator.startAnimating() // Start animating
        request.perform { data, error in
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating() // On response stop animating
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview() // remove the view
            // ... process data
        }
```

Comment: Would I add the 'UIActivityIndicatorView' to my tableView, and would this code go into the same ViewController as the TableView

Comment: You could but I do not suggest it. In the table view then the indicator will scroll with the content (it might be what you want though). the code would be similar but you would remove all the "view" calls since the table view is already a view. So for instance instead of "view.addSubview(activityIndicator)" you would call "addSubview(activityIndicator)"

Comment: Also when working with table views and the activity indicator take a look into UIRefreshControl. You can create a refresh control where the table view has a property to set it. Then just call tv.refreshControl.beginRefreshing(). This is mostly used for pull down to refresh though.

Comment: Hi Matic, I am very confused how to add this... Do I place a View on top of the table view and add a activity indicator to that view which would be a subview. Then make an outlet for the indicator and then implement your code?

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer, but it might help in case you still need it. 
The activity indicator has to be added manually.

Add `UIActivityIndicator` before the start of the `Alamofire.request` method.

```
//start the activityindicator here
UIActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

//request Alamofire
Alamofire.request
{
    //parse the response and do all the math
    //end your animator here - make sure this happens on the main thread
    UIActivityIndicator.stop()
}
```

Hope this helps you. There is no code in the solution.