# Login function with activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, authentication, uiactivityindicatorview

I am currently doing a login test and have to log in again to log in. After pressing the login button to send the request to the server, the activity indicator is displayed on the screen until the activity indicator is stopped and the activity indicator is stopped The next page, I would like to open another thread used to implement the activity indicator, but I do not know how to implement, please help!
And this code is modified from http://www.kaleidosblog.com/how-to-create-a-login-screen-page-in-swift-3-authenticate-an-user-and-keep-the-session-active.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let login_url = "http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/login/api/Login"
    let checksession_url = "http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/login/api/CheckSession"


    @IBOutlet var username_input: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var password_input: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

    var login_session:String = ""

    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        username_input.text = "try@me.com"
        password_input.text = "test"

        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle  = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray;
        activityIndicator.center = view.center;


        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        if preferences.object(forKey: "session") != nil
        {
            login_session = preferences.object(forKey: "session") as! String
            check_session()
        }



    }

    @IBAction func DoLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        login_now(username:username_input.text!, password: password_input.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func backToMain(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func login_now(username:String, password:String)
    {
        let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


        post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
        post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "password")

        let url:URL = URL(string: login_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        var paramString = ""


        for (key, value) in post_data
        {
            paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        }

        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }

            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }


            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    self.login_session = session_data

                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
                    }

                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
        LoginDone()


    }

    func check_session()
    {
        let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


        post_data.setValue(login_session, forKey: "session")

        let url:URL = URL(string: checksession_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        var paramString = ""


        for (key, value) in post_data
        {
            paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        }

        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }


            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }

            if let response_code = server_response["response_code"] as? Int
            {
                if(response_code == 200)
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }



        })

        task.resume()
    }

    func LoginDone()
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotomenu", sender: nil)
    }


    func startActivityIndicator(){
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func stopActivityIndicator() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }


}
```

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457750/use-activity-indicator-in-many-vc-without-duplicating-code-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this code code with old code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


let login_url = "http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/login/api/Login"
let checksession_url = "http://www.kaleidosblog.com/tutorial/login/api/CheckSession"


@IBOutlet var username_input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password_input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

var login_session:String = ""

var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    username_input.text = "try@me.com"
    password_input.text = "test"

    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle  = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    activityIndicator.center = view.center
    activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    if preferences.object(forKey: "session") != nil
    {
        login_session = preferences.object(forKey: "session") as! String
        check_session()
    }



}

@IBAction func DoLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    login_now(username:username_input.text!, password: password_input.text!)
}

@IBAction func backToMain(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
    startActivityIndicator()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    stopActivityIndicator()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = true
}


func login_now(username:String, password:String)
{
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    startActivityIndicator()
    let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


    post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
    post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "password")

    let url:URL = URL(string: login_url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    var paramString = ""


    for (key, value) in post_data
    {
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }

    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in
        self.stopActivityIndicator()
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }

        let json: Any?

        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {
            return
        }


        if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
            {
                self.login_session = session_data

                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.LoginDone()
                }

            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()



}

func check_session()
{
    let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


    post_data.setValue(login_session, forKey: "session")

    let url:URL = URL(string: checksession_url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    var paramString = ""


    for (key, value) in post_data
    {
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }

    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }


        let json: Any?

        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {
            return
        }

        if let response_code = server_response["response_code"] as? Int
        {
            if(response_code == 200)
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }



    })

    task.resume()
}

func LoginDone()
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotomenu", sender: nil)
}


func startActivityIndicator(){
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func stopActivityIndicator() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
}
```

Comment: But when I pressed logout button, the activity indiator didn't disappear

Comment: I apply only on log in function

Comment: It's ran successfully, but jumping to the next page will repeat twice

Comment: twice means i don't get it

Comment: There is not now! But I just test the e-mail, into the other words can jump, which some strange, I hope you can help me answer, if no way it does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use SVProgressHUD. It's the simplest framework, that I have ever seen. [SVProgressHUD on GitHub](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD)

Install:

In your podfile:

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

Then in terminal:

```
pod install
```

How to use:

```
import SVProgressHUD
```

to start:

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

to dismiss:

```
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Its very simple and usefull. Just try it.

Hope it helps